# Displaying combobox items into graph

Tags: c#, forms, graph, combobox, numbers

I'm trying to show my combobox items (Numbers) from `Form1` into a graph in `Form2`, but I can't get the value's to show in the graph. After multiple tries this is where I'm at right now, but I just can't figure out how to make it work.

Code in `Form2`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
  for (int i = 0; i < frm1.comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    int Value = Convert.ToInt16(frm1.comboBox1.Items);
    chart1.Series["Saved Results"].Points.AddXY(0, Value);
  }
}
```

When I click on `button1` nothing happens :(. Can you help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Your `frm1` is a new, blank Form1, with nothing on it (it's never been displayed or anything).  If you want to work with an **existing and open** Form1 instance, then you need to get a reference to THAT instance and not create one dynamically...

Answer (score 2):

You are converting the item collection to an Int16, which is likely nothing. Use the indexer on the items collection.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    for (int i = 0; i < frm1.comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        int Value = Convert.ToInt16(frm1.comboBox1.Items[i]);
        chart1.Series["Saved Results"].Points.AddXY(0, Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if initializing a new Form1 will produce any items in the combobox??? :P

Comment: Only God and @Keppa know for sure.